# Function keys Magic Keyboard not bound correctly

Tags: keyboard, macos

I just bought the new [Magic Keyboard](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLA22LL/A/magic-keyboard-us-english). On my Mac mini with Mac OS X El Capitan the function keys worked perfectly, but on my iMac still with Mavericks the function keys are not working... <kbd>F12</kbd> for instance (sound up) brings me to the Dashboard and so on.

Is it something I missed? Pressing <kbd>fn</kbd> isn't working either and I've checked the preference pane....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the Apple Store listing](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLA22LL/A/magic-keyboard-us-english), it very clearly says this:

> **System Requirements**
>   Bluetooth-enabled Mac computer with OS X v10.11 or later

As you have experienced, basic keyboard functions will work with older versions of OS X, but the special function keys will not. Evidently the keyboard changes the way the keys work and Mavericks just does not know how to handle it.

Your only solution is to upgrade to El Capitan or continue without using those function keys.

**References**: [Apple Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7302478?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work on Mavericks at least when connected over the USB-to-Lightning cable by applying this patch:

```
--- /System/Library/Extensions/AppleTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver.kext/Contents/Info.plist.orig  2017-01-10 20:28:14.000000000 +0100
+++ /System/Library/Extensions/AppleTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver.kext/Contents/Info.plist   2017-01-10 20:31:55.000000000 +0100
@@ -38,6 +38,38 @@
    <string>5A2053</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
+       <key>Keyboard-Event - 615</key>
+       <dict>
+           <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
+           <string>com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard</string>
+           <key>CapsLockDelay</key>
+           <integer>75</integer>
+           <key>DeviceUsagePairs</key>
+           <array>
+               <dict>
+                   <key>DeviceUsage</key>
+                   <integer>6</integer>
+                   <key>DeviceUsagePage</key>
+                   <integer>1</integer>
+               </dict>
+           </array>
+           <key>FnKeyboardUsageMap</key>
+           <string>0x00070050,0x0007004a,0x00070052,0x0007004b,0x0007002a,0x0007004c,0x0007004f,0x0007004d,0x00070051,0x0007004e,0x00070028,0x00070058</string>
+           <key>FnModifierUsage</key>
+           <integer>3</integer>
+           <key>FnModifierUsagePage</key>
+           <integer>255</integer>
+           <key>IOClass</key>
+           <string>AppleHIDKeyboardEventDriverV2</string>
+           <key>IOProviderClass</key>
+           <string>IOHIDInterface</string>
+           <key>NumLockKeyboardUsageMap</key>
+           <string>0x00070029,0x00070029,0x0007002a,0x0007002a,0x0007002b,0x0007002b,0x0007003a,0x0007003a,0x0007003b,0x0007003b,0x0007003c,0x0007003c,0x0007003d,0x0007003d,0x0007003e,0x0007003e,0x0007003f,0x0007003f,0x00070040,0x00070040,0x00070041,0x00070041,0x00070042,0x00070042,0x00070043,0x00070043,0x00070044,0x00070044,0x00070045,0x00070045,0x0007004a,0x0007004a,0x0007004b,0x0007004b,0x0007004c,0x0007004c,0x0007004d,0x0007004d,0x0007004e,0x0007004e,0x0007004f,0x0007004f,0x00070050,0x00070050,0x00070051,0x00070051,0x00070052,0x00070052,0x0007000d,0x00070059,0x0007000e,0x0007005a,0x0007000f,0x0007005b,0x00070018,0x0007005c,0x0007000c,0x0007005d,0x00070012,0x0007005e,0x00070024,0x0007005f,0x00070025,0x00070060,0x00070026,0x00070061,0x00070010,0x00070062,0x00070037,0x00070063,0x00070082,0x00070082,0x000700e0,0x000700e0,0x000700e1,0x000700e1,0x000700e2,0x000700e2,0x000700e3,0x000700e3,0x000700e4,0x000700e4,0x000700e5,0x000700e5,0x000700e6,0x000700e6,0x000700e7,0x000700e7</string>
+           <key>ProductID</key>
+           <integer>615</integer>
+           <key>VendorID</key>
+           <integer>1452</integer>
+       </dict>
        <key>Keyboard-Event - 656</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
--- /System/Library/Extensions/AppleTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTopCaseDriver.kext/Contents/Info.plist.orig   2017-01-10 20:27:50.000000000 +0100
+++ /System/Library/Extensions/AppleTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTopCaseDriver.kext/Contents/Info.plist    2017-01-10 20:44:53.000000000 +0100
@@ -38,6 +38,52 @@
    <string>5A2053</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
+       <key>USBHIDDriver</key>
+       <dict>
+           <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
+           <string>com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTopCaseDriver</string>
+           <key>IOClass</key>
+           <string>AppleUSBTopCaseHIDDriver</string>
+           <key>IOProviderClass</key>
+           <string>IOUSBInterface</string>
+           <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
+           <integer>1</integer>
+           <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
+           <string>*</string>
+           <key>ProductID</key>
+           <integer>615</integer>
+           <key>idVendor</key>
+           <integer>1452</integer>
+       </dict>
+       <key>USBHIDDriver - DM</key>
+       <dict>
+           <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
+           <string>com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTopCaseDriver</string>
+           <key>ExtendedData</key>
+           <array>
+               <integer>50399649</integer>
+               <integer>50465185</integer>
+               <integer>50530721</integer>
+               <integer>50596257</integer>
+               <integer>61868449</integer>
+               <integer>61933985</integer>
+               <integer>61999521</integer>
+               <integer>62065057</integer>
+               <integer>62261665</integer>
+           </array>
+           <key>IOClass</key>
+           <string>AppleUSBTopCaseHIDDriver</string>
+           <key>IOProviderClass</key>
+           <string>IOUSBInterface</string>
+           <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
+           <integer>1</integer>
+           <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
+           <string>0</string>
+           <key>ProductID</key>
+           <integer>615</integer>
+           <key>idVendor</key>
+           <integer>1452</integer>
+       </dict>
        <key>AppleTopCase</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
```

like so (assuming you save the patch in a file named `MagicKeyboard.patch`):

```
sudo sh -c '(cd /; patch -p0) < MagicKeyboard.patch'
```

and rebuilding the kext cache using:

```
sudo kextcache -f -update-volume /
```

After reboot your Magic Keyboard should be fully functional when connected over the cable.

Answer (score 0):

For people running into this on newer versions of macOS: try connecting your wireless keyboard with your Mac using a Lighting cable. Your Mac should then automatically fix the function key mapping (even when you disconnect afterwards)